# ¿Cómo mostrar todos los decimales de un tipo de dato usando ' | number: size ' en Angular?

Tags: angular

Tengo un servicio en Java que consulta a una base de datos y me regresa una lista, la cual contiene valores tipo Double muy grandes, y cuando los muestro en mi frontend (Angular) los muestra con un exponente y no los muestra completos como en la base de datos

Asi se muestran en la base de datos (Oracle)

```html
0.00000000130499999999998494601667672321700842198
0.00000000173999999999999356985251903913431458401
```

Asi se muestran en mi frontend

```html
1.3049999999999848e-9
1.7399999999999936e-9
```

Lo que quiero es mostrar el numero tal cual se visualiza en la base de datos, y trate de hacer lo siguiente:

```
<td>{{valores.NoOpciones | number: '1.47'}}</td>
```

le puse el .47 por que como se visualiza en la bd son 47 posiciones despues de 0. pero me lo sigue pintando mal, lo pinta asi

```html
0.00000000130499999999998480000000000000000000000
```

qué estoy haciendo mal?
como puedo mostrar correctamente el numero completo?

Answer (score 1):

Estás usando mal el pipe:

```
{{'0.00000000130499999999998494601667672321700842198' | number: '0.0-47'}}
```

El argumento del pipe contiene la cantidad de dígitos a la izquierda del punto decimal y luego la cantidad de dígitos después del punto la cual puede ser variable `0-47`

[Referencia](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe#digitsinfo)

[Ejemplo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cy7pao?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Hola, ya lo cambie a como me lo pusiste, pero lo pinta incompleto aun, lo pinta asi:  0.0000000013049999999999848

Comment: como que lo redondea y ya no muestra completo el numero por mas cantidad de digitos que le agregues

Comment: Entonces usa el tipo de dato `string` en lugar de `number` en Angular.

Comment: ya lo cambie pero lo pinta con el exponente

Comment: Agregué un ejemplo. Si el número se trata como una cadena se imprimirá completo.